# Bash Shell Scripting - Select Case Menu Not Working

Tags: bash, shell, echo, select-case

i'm quite new to shell programming.. and working on project

am doing Select Menu using the `Select Case`

below is the scripting

```
 #! /usr/bin/bash

    echo "1) Add new book"
    echo "2) Remove existing book info"
    echo "3) Update book info and quantity"
    echo "4) Search for book by title/author"
    echo "5) Process a book sold"
    echo "6) Inventory summary report"
    echo "7) Quit"

    PS3="Please enter your option: "
    select book in Add Remove update search process inventory quit
    #read book
    do
        case $book in
            1) echo "Add new book"
           echo "Title: "
           read title
           echo $title > BookDB.txt

           echo "Author: "
           read name
           echo $name > BookDB.txt

           echo "$title successfully added!"
           break
           ;;

            2) echo "Remove existing book info"
                sed '$NAME' BookDB.txt
           break
           ;;

            3) echo "Update book info and quantity"
           echo "Title: "
           read title
           echo $title < BookDB.txt

           echo "Author: "
           read name
           echo $name < BookDB.txt
           break
           ;;  

            4) echo "Search for book by title/author"
           break
           ;;

            5) echo "Process a book sold"
           break
           ;;

            6) echo "Inventory summary report"
           break
           ;;

            7) echo "Quit"
           exit   
           ;;
        esac
    done
```

and below is the `shell commands` in the `Ubuntu terminal`

```
1) Add new book
2) Remove existing book info
3) Update book info and quantity
4) Search for book by title/author
5) Process a book sold
6) Inventory summary report
7) Quit
1) Add        3) update     5) process    7) quit
2) Remove     4) search     6) inventory
Please enter your option: 1
Please enter your option:
```

the words in the `echo` do not appear after i entered 1.and even if i I choose Quit, it doesn't go back to the menu. how do i get it to work? :(

Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
PS3="Please enter your option: "
select book in Add Remove Update Search Process Inventory Quit
do
    case $book in
        "Add") 
            ...
            ;;
        "Remove") 
            ...
            ;;

        "Update")
            ...
            ;;  

        etc...

    esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `bash` manpage (my italics and bold):

> `select name [ in word ] ; do list ; done`
>
> The list of words following in is expanded, generating a list of items. The set of expanded words is printed on the standard error, each preceded by a number. If the in word is omitted, the positional parameters are printed (see PARAMETERS below).
>
> The PS3 prompt is  then  displayed and a line read from the standard input.
>
> *If the line consists of a number corresponding to one of the displayed words, then the value of name is set to that **word.***
>
> If the line is empty, the words and prompt are displayed again.  If EOF is read, the command completes.
>
> Any other value read causes name to be set to null.  The line read is saved in the variable REPLY.  The list is executed after each selection until a break command is executed.
>
> The exit status of select is the exit status of the  last  command executed in list, or zero if no commands were executed.

Hence, in your `case` statement, you need `"Add"` rather than `1`, ditto for the others.

---

You should also look into what you're actually *doing* in each case. Obviously the latter ones are empty because you haven't yet gotten around to them, but your use of `sed` in the second case will not remove anything from the file as it stands. And, for the third case:

```
echo $title < BookDB.txt
```

in ... interesting. If it were *output* redirection, I could understand the beginnings of a plan but the line as you have it will simply output `$title` and totally ignore the content of your input redirection.

No doubt you'll fix them in time, I just thought I'd bring them to your attention as something that needs looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> ```
> select book in Add Remove update search process inventory quit
> ```

With:

> ```
> select book in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Under select statement, in case you should use the string stated in select. Here you should do it like this:

```
select book in Add Remove update search process inventory quit
do
    case $book in
        Add) echo "Add new book"
            echo "Title: "
            read title
            echo $title > BookDB.txt

            echo "Author: "
            read name
            echo $name > BookDB.txt

            echo "$title successfully added!"
            break
            ;;

        Remove) echo "Remove existing book info"
            sed '$NAME' BookDB.txt
            break
            ;;

        update) echo "Update book info and quantity"
            echo "Title: "
            read title
            echo $title < BookDB.txt

            echo "Author: "
            read name
            echo $name < BookDB.txt
            break
            ;;

        search) echo "Search for book by title/author"
            break
            ;;

        process) echo "Process a book sold"
            break
            ;;

        inventory) echo "Inventory summary report"
            break
            ;;

        quit) echo "Quit"
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done
```

You can understand the code as below:

1. select prepare many values for book, and which value assigned is due to what we input. The input should be integer indexed begin from 1.
2. For further understanding, you should learn much about bash and select system call.